# Is it possible to put data tables created within user-defined function in the global environment?

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating a user-defined function which helps me to create 20+ data tables. However, these data tables do not get created in the global environment, unlike when not using user-defined function. See the sample code below.

```
library(data.table)
samplefunction <- function(f) {
  df=as.data.table(list(V1=c('a','a','b','c'),V2=c(1,2,3,4)))
  df.a=df[V1==f]
  df.a
}
samplefunction('a')
```

I only know whether the function works provided the line df.a outputs the data.table in the console window, because df and df.a data tables do not get created in the global environment. I will not be able to view my data tables in this way. Is it possible to create the tables in the global environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<<-` operator instead of `=` to assign `df.a` as a global variable in the function:

```
samplefunction <- function(f) {
    df=as.data.table(list(V1=c('a','a','b','c'),V2=c(1,2,3,4)))
    df.a <<- df[V1==f]
}

samplefunction('a')
df.a
```

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html

Or you could just have the function return a list of the data tables and use standard assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @Nat's second answer is the better choice:

```
samplefunction <- function(f) {
  df=as.data.table(list(V1=c('a','a','b','c'),V2=c(1,2,3,4)))
  df.a=df[V1==f]

  return(list("df"=df, "df.a"=df.a)
}
```

Global assignment can overwrite objects in the global environment, which is usually bad. With the modification of the function here, you can then use it as follows:

```
myresults <- samplefunction(input)
# show df
myresults[["df"]]
# show df.a
myresults[["df.a"]]
```